# Can't serial print in setup() using HiLetgo ESP8266 with ESP8266WiFi.h library and Arduino IDE

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, arduino-esp8266

When I `Serial.print()` anything within the setup function using the Arduino library and IDE, I don't get anything. But when I move the `Serial.print()` lines to the loop function they appear normally. The code in `setup()` seems to be running. I just can't print anything to serial.

Comment: You need to share your code. Possibly you have no serial init at the top of the setup().

Comment: Thanks for the responses! It turns out I just had to put a delay of about 1000ms after `Serial.begin(115200)`.

Comment: So it is cool than. Somehow uart looks not ready. Congs for your effort. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Add a delay of 1000ms before `Serial.begin(115200)`.

Answer (score 0):

Put these lines at the top of the setup :

```
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.setDebugOutput(true);
```